# Why "parameters" is not defined

Tags: python, python-requests

I am following the tutorial at https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-api-tutorial/. It is saying that "parameters" is not defined. The URL has params=parameters, I have used both in the coding and still getting error. Not sure how to correct it.

This is the code:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json", params=parameters)

def jprint(obj):
        # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
        text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        print(text)

parameters = {
    "lat":27.8006,
    "lon":97.3864
}

jprint(response.json())
```

Comment: The order is important. Define `parameters` *before* you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `parameters` before you've actually initialised it. Move your `parameters` dictionary above the `response`.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeoren has said you are using your parameters variable before it has been defined. to fix this issue you must move your declaration of parameters above your response code like so:

```
import requests
import json

parameters = {
    "lat":27.8006,
    "lon":97.3864
}

response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json", params=parameters)

def jprint(obj):
        # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
        text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        print(text)

jprint(response.json())
```